# PhpStorm HTML inspection issue

Tags: javascript, html, ide, phpstorm, code-inspection

I can't figure out why PhpStorm IDE is treating src HTML attribute as a JavaScript code (or a kind of regular expression). After code inspection this error is assigned to "JavaScript validity issues".

Have someone resolved this error before? Can I solve it some other way than turning off inspection?

[image: Expression statement is not assignment or call]

Comment: Somehow you have made this happen (yes, this is user-created issue -- you must have been typing/pressing lots of keys too fast without looking at a screen). Please post screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: Oh well, I had the "xml: img/@src" injection checked. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

As @LazyOne wrote, the solution to this issue was to uncheck the `xml: img/@src` language injection in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`:

[image: PhpStorm preferences]

Comment: Not to just "uncheck" but to actually delete that rule. You have created that rule by mistake without even noticing it -- there is no reason at all to still keep it there .. and then few months/year later wonder what it's for and why it's disabled.